# Japanese font does not appear in substitute font in PlotToPDF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

When converting a dwg file using Japanese characters of "HG丸ゴシックM-PRO" font to PDF using PlotToPDF, the Japanese characters become "?".
I want to be able to display this in alternate font.
In the case of the "MSゴシック" font, conversion is possible without problems.

"HG丸ゴシックM-PRO" font is included in MS-Office Japanese version.

I tryed change script to below in PlotToPDF Activity,
But the result did not change

```
"Script": "_FONTALT extfont2.shx\n_layoutcreateviewport 1 _tilemode 0 -export _pdf _all result.pdf\n"
```

●Target dwg file : jp_test.dwg
●Results of AutoCAD2020 output : AC2020.pdf
●Results of PlotToPDF output : PlotToPDF(23.1).pdf
●Results of PlotToPDF edited script output : PlotToPDF231_JPN.pdf

These are included in the following zip file
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlrvGXP_bP3HvTNoIvn_FH9wtpnO

Please let me know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle custom fonts (`HG丸ゴシックM-PRO` is obviously not available to our cloud runtime by default) in your appPackage under the `Contents folder` and specify that path in the `SupportPath` attribute in your `PackageContents.xml` for the runtime to pick the fonts up:

```
<Components>
    <RuntimeRequirements
        OS="Win64"
        Platform="AutoCAD" 
        SupportPath="./Contents/"/>
    <ComponentEntry
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  
I did not understand about appPackage until now.  
I will create and try.

Comment: What is file "PlotLayout.dll"? Where can I get it from?

Comment: That's your the assembly of YOUR plugin ... which should be built from your source code - see [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/designautomation/appbundle/engines/autocad) for details

Comment: To add a font, not just place a font file, do I have to create a plug-in?

Comment: If I want to use additional fonts, can I not use the PlotToPDF activity?
Need to create a program (plugin) for PDF output?

Comment: Yes unfortunately you will need to create a plugin of your own to bundle custom fonts

Comment: Oh, thank you.
It is inefficient to download the entire font every time we call the API. I will try to think of other ways.

Comment: You don't need to download the entire font at any time ... but I will let you figure things out